# regex match everything after N column (delimiter is ,)

Tags: regex, pycharm, textmate

How can I match data after third column? (textmate or pycharm ...) `('col1', 'col2', 'col3'MATCH`

Input

```
(175, 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'Плата печатная в сборе, готовая к установке в корпус БУД-420М.', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', '', '', 'Плата печатная в сборе, готовая к установке в корпус БУД-420М.', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М'),
```

Match

```
, 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', '', '', 'Плата печатная в сборе, готовая к установке в корпус БУД-420М.', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М', 'ЗИП БУД-420М'),
```

Comment: You could do capture. Are you really trying to do matching? Why?

Comment: @AvinashRaj there are thousands lines of data ... I cant capture it cause in x line there is data in column xJ but in y line there is not data in yJ etc ...

Comment: @karthikmanchala I need only three first columns ... everything else match for remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need only three first columns

You can use the following for matching first 3 columns:

```
^('?)[^']*\1,(?:[^']*'[^']*'){2}
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/21)